# How to make drop down list in css like .dropdown:focus .dropdown-content

Tags: html, css, asp.net

When I click on some link in the dropdown content,
the dropdown content disappears (because its :focus),
There is any solution?

CSS:

```
.dropdown:focus .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    z-index: 11;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown" tabindex="0">
                <asp:Image ID="logo" alt="LpcTube" class="logo_img" runat="server" />
                <div class="dropdown-content border">


                    <div class="moveMenuHover">
                    <asp:Label ID="lOption" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I don't want use :hover..

Answer (score 0):

if you insist to use the :focus, you have to set it on the container that contains both classes inside (.dropdown and .dropdown-content). that way the dropdown won't disappear.

The best practice is to use hover not focus.